# Generate a dynamic URL within email HTML

Tags: email, dynamic, html-email, email-attachments

I am having trouble finding a solution to this and would love to any thoughts or suggestions.

**The overall aim is to dynamically generate a private link within an email, used to  register/login users anonymously.** Only those with a link will be able to access the app, and they will otherwise remain anonymous (i.e no link to their email address - identified only by the number included within the dynamic link). Obviously, if they share this URL, anyone can log in as them.

I would like to generate some sort of embed code that customers may copy/paste as part of an email template. Ideally, This code would dynamically create a unique identifier for each recipient on delivery. We will not be able to send a dedicated email to do this. For example, a customer clicks 'Generate embed link' within the admin panel. They will be provided with a html string that they may include within their email template, eg:

```
<html :href="www.myapp.com/customer1/register/batch1/{{dynamic_id}}"></html>
```

On receiving this email, the link may look like this:

```
<html :href="www.myapp.com/customer1/register/batch1/7877346"></html>
```

The idea is that the user could click the link and automatically register/log in using this URL. It is crucial that no one can see this URL other than the recipient, and there is no way of linking the sent email back to the dynamically generated ID. GDPR, bah :(

Hope this makes sense. Happy to hear alternative solutions or limitations here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a code generator (in which case, what language(s) are available to you? What platform(s) are you using?), or the format of the output?

Comment: Hi there, I am using VueJS which consumes a Laravel API (w/ PHP), though open to hearing solutions outside of these.

To clarify - I am wondering is it possible for a generic email, sent to multiple addresses at once, to include a unique dynamically generated value for each recipient.

I was thinking that perhaps some sort of code snippet could be added to an existing email template. When the admin wants to send a batch of emails, they simply include the snippet and a dynamic URL will be rendered within the email (e.g mysite.com/user=4)

Thanks and hope this makes sense.

Comment: So, when you're constructing the email code, what's your difficulty with adding a variable from your data into the href? You can certainly do that, but you'd need to know how the email code is being constructed, and modify that.